# Select after merge: Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to select an entity with it's children (join) after having merged (updated) the same entity within the same service (transaction). I know that merge return the object you updated but this object has the data which has been updated, not all the entity with the data of the database. Additionally, If after merging I execute an select trying to get the entity with all it's children, it return's the object updated only with the data updated (the rest of fields and children entities are null).

is there any way to resolve it? It's mandatory to execute everything in the same transaction because the service have a lot of database operations that must be executed correctly before committing.

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: Show us your code. The entity returned by merge is an attached entity containing what IS in the database, or at least what will be in the database once the session is flushed. If the rest of the fields are null, then it means those will be null in the database once the session is flushed, which means you have a big problem.

Comment: You are right but I just want to update one field of the entity, so I built the entity object just with this field, the rest are null. So what I can understand of your answer, I have to build the entity all the fields... Isn't there a way to update just the fields I want to updated?

Comment: Then get the entity from the session, and set the field: `Foo f = session.get(Foo.class, id); f.setSomeField(newValue);System.out.println("done");`

Comment: So every time I want to update an object, all the objects of the entity must be set before updating, am I right?

Comment: Yes. What is in the entity matches what is in the database. If you set everything to null in an entity, you're telling Hibernate to set everything to null in the database. That's the principle of object-relational mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you have structured your code. It would help if you can provide more information/code for what you are trying to achieve.

From your description, check, if you have set the cascade option properly between the entity and its children. You can set the cascade for Merge operation, which should refresh the children also. (Note: This would work only if any of the children were fetched before merge operation in case of lazy loading).

And for your second question, again it depends on how you have structured your code, and the way you are fetching data from db.
But, ideally, all the database operations related to one request/unit of work should be handled inside one transaction.

Comment: I don't want to update on cascade... I have a row on my database that it is shown on my jsp. I only have one field to be modified, then I submit the object that contains this modification (so the entity has the id and the field modified, rest of fields are null). My intention it to update just the modified fields but now I have my doubts that I could be done.

Comment: You can try creating a new entity having only the Id and the modified field. Don't add all other fields (for which you pass null as value) to this entity. Hope this solves your problem.